# openpyxl - insert new worksheet on existing workbook, made the new worksheet is active and inactive the existing sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm newbie on python programming and right now using python 3.10.7 and I have excel file just called example1.xlsx and it have one sheet named data1. i want to insert new worksheet named filter and made it as active one and then inactive data1 worksheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# Load the Excel file

wb = load_workbook('example1.xlsx')

# Create a new worksheet
new_sheet = wb.create_sheet(index=0)
# Set the title of the new worksheet
new_sheet.title = 'filter'

sheet1 = wb['filter']
sheet2 = wb['data1']
# Set sheet1 as the active sheet
wb.active = sheet1






# Save the changes made to the Excel file
wb.save('example1.xlsx')
```

I just tried to make filter worksheet as the active sheet:

```
sheet1 = wb['filter']
sheet2 = wb['data1']
# Set sheet1 as the active sheet
wb.active = sheet1
```

but why the validation result shown as picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBVqQ.png)

it seen both worksheet are active

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: The `'active' sheet` is just the last sheet with the focus when the workbook was saved, if you assign a worksheet object to the `'active sheet'` it will be whichever sheet that was, (which could still be accessed by its own sheet name). It doesn't mean that's the only sheet that can be accessed, read from or written to. You have assigned the worksheet objects `sheet1 = wb['filter']` and `sheet2 = wb['data1']` so if you want to read/write to the sheet named `'filter'` then use the object `'sheet1'` and if you wanted to read/write to the sheet `'data1'` then use the worksheet object `'sheet2'`.